# redirect direct image if not used in image tag

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

We have some static images, publicly available. However, we want to be able to redirect that images if not used in image tag,
ex:

```
http://server.com/img/my_cool_image.jpg
```

i want to if some one open it directly with that link it will be redirect to the home page 
`http://server.com`
but if that were used in image(src) tag it will opened normaly

```
<img src="http://server.com/img/my_cool_image.jpg">
```

is threre any way to do something like that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check HTTP_REFERER. If refer is set that means it is not direct access using manual input in browser address bar. HTTP_REFERER is the way to know where the comes from (previous page/site, etc)

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
   redirect('http://server.com');
}
```

Comment: but i need to put that code to where? is there any way to write same code for nginx?

Comment: you need to put the code in your pages. One way to do efficiently is to create separate file and include in all pages at top `include('referer.php')`.

Comment: @EmanDev if this the answer given help you, accept the answer to close the topic.